# Tweet from a custom dialog box button

Tags: android, string, twitter, dialog

I'm trying to send a tweet whenever the user enters text into the edit text which will then be able to convert into a string and then be tweeted. but I can't get it to send. How could I do this? Here is my code

```
   public void onClick1(View v) {
        //String status = editTextStatus.getText().toString();
        String token ="token"; 
        String secret = "secret";
        AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token,secret);
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer("auth", "auth secret");
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
        try {
            //String status1 = editTextStatus.getText().toString();
            twitter.updateStatus(editTextStatus.getText().toString());
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error/exception?

Comment: Not at all, it just doesn't publish it to my twitter. @AbhishekV

Comment: Have you registered your application in twitter? Have you entered proper `token` and `secret`?

Comment: @AbhishekV Yes I have. I'm thinking maybe I need to make it log in but I don't really know how to do that. I got a tutorial that helped me do it but with another thing and that works, but I don't know how to initialize a log in from there